# How can my NPC chase a caster PC who tries to cast a spell and my NPC wants to stay within range to counterspell the PC?

Tags: dnd-5e, counterspelling

Assuming an NPC of mine plays the role of **counterspell** dude for the bad guys.
If the PC starts running in order to always be out of range of 60ft (for the counterspell to be able to cast), how will the NPC be able to keep up in order to cast it?

I mean, it's a reaction spell but it's a game where we take turns, so the "*I'm on your tail*" style of chase can't be realistic in this scenario and the game kinda breaks. So it's practically impossible for the NPC to be on a PC's tail if the PC keeps running around. If there is a way around, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: what spell are the PCs trying to cast, I ask because the answers would be different if they are expending an Action or Bonus Action to cast something.

Comment: Also, are we assuming two characters with identical Speeds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If they start within 30 feet then the PC can't get out of range

Unless they are a Rogue or Fighter or similar.

If the PC moves 30 feet and casts then they are still within the 60 foot range of counterspell.

If the PC uses dash to move 60 feet then they don't have an action left to cast a spell, unless they can dash as a bonus action (Rogue) or use Action Surge (fighter) or something similar.

Since the counterspeller doesn't need their action for anything, they can always use dash to get back within 30 feet of the PC, ready to use their Reaction.

### Is this useful? Maybe

What this does is is tie up the NPC's actions. If they is continually running after the PC then they aren't attacking the rest of the party. In online games, this is called "kiting".

As [Hellsaint](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/43856/hellsaint) pointed out in a comment, this also means the PC is doing nothing. PC actions are usually much more important than NPC actions, so kiting in D&D is often not worth it for players. As a DM, using an NPC to kite a player in this way is a great tactic. *evil laugh*

### The NPCs should be using battlefield control

The PC can't run out of counterspell range if they are in a web or erupting earth area, or if they are slowed or held.

Comment: To be fair - the NPC is not doing anything, but the PC isn't either. And usually a PC action is more useful than a minion action, mainly if the minion is solely designed to stop the PC's action, which he is doing without even spending his counterspell in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

### NPCs are not PCs but ...

There are ways for PCs to extend the range of a spell. See [Does Spell Sniper and Distant Spell quadruple your range on attack spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112271/does-spell-sniper-and-distant-spell-quadruple-your-range-on-attack-spells) (TL;DR Yes it does).

Of course NPCs can have their own abilities which are inaccessble to PCs, for example:

> **Spell Supressor:** When casting *Counterspell* the range is 120 feet.

or

> **Quick Reactions:** Immediately before casting a spell with a casting time of 1 Reaction, the caster can move (or teleport?) up to 30 feet.